# How to do proper formatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to specify outliers on a plot of data and I want a scale of y-axis to have the same values as in a data frame.

my plot is

[image]

This is the data frame and my code.

```
date_x=sd.iloc[0:,0]
volume_y=sd.iloc[0:,1]
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.scatter(date_x,volume_y,marker="o");
y_formatter=matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
plt.title("Volume of Microsoft Over Time")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Volume")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide your original dataframe/code, in order to reproduce the plot. In addition, give more details what you intend to show in the plot. It is a bit confuse

Comment: I vote to close, because it's not clear what you're asking for due to insufficient (missing?) details given in the question body. I suggest that you [edit] your Q to provide more info.

Comment: just plot the outliers in red and the rest of the data in blue. you will need to first detect those outliers though. There are tons of methods for outlier detection, pick one and use it, the simplest one is any point greater than k times the standard deviation.